# Cox proportional hazards models for an individual patient's risk prediction?

Tags: neural-networks, cox-model

Some [researchers](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Ecnyu/papers/nips11_survival.pdf) claim that Cox-based models fail in a precise estimation
of the survival time of an individual patient, but are rather used for the population's risk estimation. They suggest deep learning as an alternative for more accurate prediction at the individual level.

Do you agree with that?